# PHP Mysql Table Pagination

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, pagination

Ive been try to make a page with Pagination on table. Upon button click, the table in main.php got populated by the first 16 rows retrieved from the query in page.php. For example the retrieved rows were 20. So there would be an excess of 4 for the second page. The thing is when I clicked the "Next" button to show the missing 4 records, the page is then diverted to page.php with the missing records. What I want to happen is for the 20 records in main.php be replaced by the 4 records.

**MAIN.PHP**

```
<div id="section">
    <head3>Asset Assignment</head3><br><br>
    <table>
        <td>
            <tr>Search Asset:</tr>
            <tr><input type="text" id="sidt" name="sid"></tr>
            <tr><input type="button" name="searchSub" value="Search" onClick="searchItem()"></tr>
        </td>
    </table><br>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Employee ID</td>
            <td>Asset Serial Number</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" name="empID"></td> 
            <td><input type="text" name="srlID"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="right"><input type="button" name="assign" value="Assign" onClick="assignItem()"></td>
        </tr>
    </table><br>
</div>
<div id="section2"></div>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
function searchItem()
{   
    var xhr;  
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();  
    } 
    else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
        xhr = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }  
    var data = "asid=" + document.getElementById("sidt").value;
    xhr.open("POST", "page.php", true);   
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");              
    xhr.send(data);  
    xhr.onreadystatechange = display_data; 
    function display_data() 
    {  
        if (xhr.readyState == 4) 
        { 
            if (xhr.status == 200) 
            {       
                document.getElementById("section2").innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
            } 
            else 
            { 
                alert('There was a problem with the request.');  
            }  
        }  
    }  
}
function assignItem(){}
```

PAGE.PHP

```
<?PHP
session_start();
$dbHost     = "localhost";
$dbUser     = "root"; 
$dbPass     = "password";
$dbDatabase = "awsims";
$db         = new PDO("mysql:dbname=$dbDatabase;host=$dbHost;port=3306", $dbUser, $dbPass); 
if (!isset($_GET['startrow']) or !is_numeric($_GET['startrow'])) {
  $startrow = 0;
} else {
  $startrow = (int)$_GET['startrow'];
}
$sql = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM assets LIMIT $startrow, 16");
$sql->execute();
$fetch = $sql->rowCount();
$num=$fetch;
if($num>0)
{
    echo "<table style='width: 100%' border='1'>";
    echo "<tr><td>ID</td><td>Drug</td><td>quantity</td></tr>";
    for($i=0;$i<$num;$i++)
    {
        $row = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $a = $row['SerialNumber'];
        $b = $row['AssetType'];
        $c = $row['AssetSubType'];
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>$a</td>";
        echo "<td>$b</td>";
        echo "<td>$c</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
}
echo '<a href='.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?startrow='.($startrow+16).'>Next</a>';
$prev = $startrow - 16;
        //if ($prev >= 0)
echo '<a href='.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?startrow='.$prev.'>Previous</a>';
?>
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem? The fact that the link takes you to a new page, or something else? Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: The page.php must not be shown whenever i click "Next". The table in the main.php should refresh instead.

Comment: This question is a little too broad, but the technology you are looking for is called AJAX. Search for it, read a tutorial or two, then come back here if you get stuck.

Comment: I've already tried it. My problem here is that on button click i was able to retrieve all data, once the rows retrieve is < 16 the Pagination should take place. The problem is whenever the rows exceeds 16 and I have to click "Next" to see the second page of the table. Main.php brings me to Page.php with the said rows for the second page. What I've been trying to do is the stay on Main.php with the second row. Sorry if my question is quite vague.

Comment: You need to write an event handler for your link, rather than using the `href` property. The page change happens because clicking the link sends the user to the URL specified in the `href` property. You need to intercept that click, disable the default event (the navigation), and use AJAX to fetch the results.

Comment: do you desire a page section refresh without reload which is what I believe  @EdCottrell is suggesting

Comment: I just want the output from the page.php to be inserted in main.php upon clicking "Next" and I have no idea since the script in main.php calls page.php.

Comment: can you please improve question in sentences 2 and beyond via [edit]. Thanks Cain

Comment: so i think sentences 2 and 3 are like not helpful (read: crap)

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your sql statement to as following query.

```
$sql = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM assets LIMIT 16 OFFSET $startrow");
```

The next and previous link code should be like following.

```
echo '<a href='.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?startrow='.($startrow+1).'>Next</a>';
$prev = $startrow - 1;
echo '<a href='.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?startrow='.$prev.'>Previous</a>';
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is the easiest and smartest [PHP MySQL Pagination](http://www.muwakaba.com/php-mysql-pagination) example I had ever read! Very well explained and a full code is provided which is tested and working 100%.

Comment: Link is broken.